Is it possible to squeeze into a Smaller Space?
The 2014 Player's Handbook (p. 192) includes a rule for Squeezing into a Smaller Space:

Squeezing into a Smaller Space. A creature can squeeze through a space that is large enough for a creature one size smaller than it.
Thus, a Large creature can squeeze through a passage that's only 5
feet wide. While squeezing through a space, a creature must spend 1
extra foot for every foot it moves there, and it has disadvantage on
attack rolls and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the
creature have advantage while it's in the smaller space.

This rule isn't in the 2024 PHB or DMG. Is it possible to squeeze under the 2024 rules?

Yes
It's true that the quoted rule isn't in the 2024 PHB, but according to the sidebar "What's new in the 2024 Version?", on p. 5:

If you can't find a rule, check the index. If a rule's name has
changed from what was printed in the 2014 Player's Handbook, the index
points you to the new name. For example, if you look up Inspiration in
the index, it points you to the rules for Heroic Inspiration in the
rules glossary.

And we can still find the term squeezing in the index on p. 383:

squeezing. See Difficult Terrain, 24, 366

The rules
Difficult Terrain on p. 24 states:

Combatants are often slowed down by Difficult Terrain. Low furniture,
rubble, undergrowth, steep stairs, snow, and shallow bogs are examples
of Difficult Terrain.
Every foot of movement in Difficult Terrain costs 1 extra foot, even
if multiple things in a space count as Difficult Terrain.

And in the Rules Glossary, Difficult Terrain on p. 366 states (emphasis mine):

If a space is Difficult Terrain, every foot of movement in that space
costs 1 extra foot. For example, moving 5 feet through Difficult
Terrain costs 10 feet of movement. Difficult Terrain isn’t cumulative;
either a space is Difficult Terrain or it isn’t.
A space is Difficult Terrain if the space contains any of the
following or something similar:

A creature that isn’t Tiny or your ally
Furniture that is sized for    creatures of your size or larger
Heavy snow, ice, rubble, or    undergrowth
Liquid that’s between shin- and waist-deep
A narrow opening sized for a creature one size smaller than you
A slope of 20 degrees or more


Conclusion
The emphasized sentence, "A narrow opening sized for a creature one size smaller than you", along with the Difficult Terrain rules, represents the 2024 equivalent of the 2014 text.
